# Não consigo chamar um método assíncrono na view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou tentando chamar este método **assíncrono** na view mas não consigo.

```
private async Task LogOff()
{
   RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
}
```

Esta é uma das formas que estou tentando chamar não consigo.

```html
<script>
    $(".sair").click(function () {
        $.get("../Login/LogOff", function(data, status) {
             alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
             });
        });
</script>
```

A Outra forma que também tentei chamar mas não funcionou.

```html
<a class="nav-link text-dark sair" asp-area="" asp-controller="Login" asp-action="LogOff">Sair</a>
```

Comment: Por que você não consegue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a segunda forma de realizar logout, porém ajuste o código do seu controller para o seguinte:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LogOff()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Você deve retornar uma view e chamar o método `SignOutAsync` antes de retorná-la.